# Error al obtener las fechas en query SQLite

Tags: android, date, android-sqlite

Hola sucede que tenia problema para obtener los registros del campo fecha de una tabla sqlite, ahora he corregido mi codigo para obtener fechas así:

```html
do
    {
     inicio=new Entidades.TablaInicio(inicio);
     inicio.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.id)));
     inicio.setNombre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Nombre)));
     /*------- Fecha -----------*/
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     try {
         inicio.setFecha(sdf.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Fecha))));
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         //Error formato no adecuado.
     }
     listinicio.add(inicio);
   }
```

El problema es que me lanza este error

```html
ATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.home.sb, PID: 9936 java.lang.NullPointerException at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1009) at java.text.DateFormat.parse
```

justo en esta linea

```html
     inicio.setFecha(sdf.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Fecha))));
```

Gracias por leer.
Esto lo hago en un fragment.

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es la columna que almacena la fecha en SQLite? Si es del tipo String, haces un `getString` normal y luego formateas el valor en la variable que lo recupera. Me parece que no existe un método `getDate` para SQLite.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano Es de tipo DATE pero si escribo cursor.getDate me lo pone en rojo como si no existiera ese método

Comment: No existe en efecto. SQLite guarda las fechas como cadenas. Debes usar `getString` y luego formatear el resultado en la salida.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias nuevamente, pero como podria formatear la salida?

Comment: Comentas en la respuesta de @JocksanCruz que si le pones `getString` te lo pone en rojo  ¿?  ¿Cómo tienes declarada la columna que almacena la fecha?  ¿Cómo es el código  donde intentas recuperar el valor (el que dices que te pone en rojo)?

Comment: Puedes usar cursor.getString() para obtener el valor de tu campo definido como DATE y después usarías [DateFormat.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) para convertirlo a Date y agregarlo a tu objeto. Te sugiero primeramente revises los dos puntos que comento en mi respuesta. @Geek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noto varios detalles a comentar, esto antes de comentar como extraer los datos.

Primeramente noto que deseas agregar a tu tabla además de la fecha los valores de ID y Nombre:

```
inicio.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.id)));       
inicio.setNombre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Nombre)));
inicio.setFecha(dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Fecha))));
```

para esto el script de creación de tu tabla debe ser diferente, debes agregar a la estructura los campos necesarios, realizalo de esta forma:

```
//public static final String crearTablaInicio = " create table " + TablaI + "(" +fecha + " Date ");
public static final String crearTablaInicio = " create table " + TablaI + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nombre TEXT, " +fecha + " Date ");
```

No puedes insertar u obtener los demás campos id y nombre si estos no existen en tu tabla.

---

Ahora el query para obtener los valores mediante un `Select` , si tu campo se llama "idU" debes asegurarte que este sea el nombre definido al crear la tabla.

Es importante mencionar que no necesitas agregar como contenedor las comillas ( '' ) ya que NO es un campo tipo `TEXT`, es `INTEGER`, si es un campo `INTEGER`, esto debe cambiar.

```
//String query="Select * from " + _inicio_Utilidades.TablaInicio +" where idU= '"+idU+"'";
String query="Select * from " + _inicio_Utilidades.TablaInicio +" where idU= "+idU;
```

---

Ahora para extraer el valor de tu tabla y este agregarlo a el campo tipo `Date` de tu objeto puedes usar la clase [**DateFormat**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) y usar su método [**parse()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) para convertir a `Date`:

```
...
...
   do
    {
     inicio=new Entidades.TablaInicio(inicio);
     inicio.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.id)));
     inicio.setNombre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Nombre)));
     /*------- Fecha -----------*/
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     try {
         inicio.setFecha(sdf.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Fecha))));
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         //Error formato no adecuado.
     }
     listinicio.add(inicio);
   }
...
...
```

Comment: gracias por responder me lanza este error FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.home.sb, PID: 9936
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1009)
                      at java.text.DateFormat.parse

Comment: Estas llamando sdf.parse() pero recuerda que es importante inicializar sdf, lo cual se realiza aquí : SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Hola, ya lo tengo inicializado y manda ese error :c

Comment: @Geek revisa que tengas este import : import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Comment: Hola, si lo tengo :/

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el `getString` y luego darle formato, te puede funcionar:

```
String dateTime = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_INDEX));
```

Para darle formato:

```
DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try 
{
    date = iso8601Format.parse(dateTime);
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    Log.e(TAG, "Parsing ISO8601 datetime failed", e);
}
```

O con `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d=new Date();
try 
{
    d=  dateFormat.parse(dateTime);
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Y en tu cursor:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
do 
{
    inicio=new Entidades.TablaInicio(inicio);              
    inicio.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.id)));       
    inicio.setNombre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Nombre)));
    <---mas campos-->
    inicio.setFecha(dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Fecha))));
    listinicio.add(inicio);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Hola @Jocksan eso si lo comprendo, pero como obtengo el dato Date de la consulta con el cursor?, porque si lo  hago cursor.getString me lo pone en rojo porque el campo es Date

Comment: No deberi'a darte problema: `String dateTime = row.getString(row.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_INDEX));`

Comment: Hola he actualizado mi pregunta, no uso una variable para guardar el valor del query, en mi pregunta explico como lo estoy guardando.

Comment: @Geek, editada la respuesta, a ver si te funciona. Saludos,

Comment: Hola gracias me manda una excepcion null y ahora ya no me muestra ningun dato

Comment: E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.DayView.generateRippleDrawable me muestra este error en consola

Comment: Si comentas la línea que obtiene la fecha no te da el error?

Comment: Si, en esta linea  inicio.setFecha(dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio_Utilidades.Fecha))));